# How do you merge two same-format xml files using xQuery so that the merged file is ordered by timestamp?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have two xml files, both of which contain multiple `<Message>` elements, like this:

```
<!--CodeSite Log File-->
<!--Created on 12 December 2018 13:58:52 -->
<CodeSiteLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CodeSiteLogFile.xsd">
. . .
  <Message MsgType="Enter" MsgText="CStore">
    <TimeStamp Date="2018-12-11" Time="11:10:40.860" TimeBias="0"/>
    <ProcessID>7688</ProcessID>
    <ThreadName>7</ThreadName>
    <AppName>spoolsv</AppName>
    <ComputerName>W10-X64-BPT</ComputerName>
    <Category Color="clWhite" FontColor="clBlack"></Category>
    <TypeName></TypeName>
  </Message>
. . .
</CodeSiteLog>
```

My question is, how can I use xQuery to merge those two xml files into a single xml file that is ordered by ascending TimeStamp?  I've been able to merge the two files, but I get all the Messages from the first xml file followed by all the Messages from the second xml file, rather than ordered by ascending TimeStamp.

I currently get a merged file that looks like this, where the first two Messages are from the first file, and the remainder are from the second file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <result MsgText="message from first log" MsgType="Info" Time="11:10:40.858"/>
  <result MsgText="message from first log" MsgType="Info" Time="11:10:41.778"/>
  <result MsgText="message from second log" MsgType="Info" Time="11:10:30.791"/>
  <result MsgText="message from second log" MsgType="Info" Time="11:10:30.801"/>
  . . .
</results>
```

But the Messages in the merged file aren't in timestamp order any more.

Comment: It's a good idea to show us your code so we can see where you went wrong. Otherwise we're just writing the code for you, rather than giving you feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence,

```
for $m in (doc('a.xml'), doc('b.xml'))//Message
order by $m/Timestamp/dateTime(@Date, @Time)
return $m
```